# String Keyword Searching in Python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list, search

I am trying to find a keyword in any index in a list and grab that index. I have created a small web scraper using BeautifulSoup4 to scrape fanfiction data.

Since not all fanfictions have genres or characters listed, or even an update date(if they are newly published) all of the info will be in different indexes.

I therefore need to search for, lets say, 'Words: ' and get the index for the whole string, ie 'Words: 1,854' == list[3], or something like that, and save it as the variable words = list[3] to call on later, in order to put it into an excel file later in the correct columns. Here is my current scraper, it is only set to scrape one page at the moment, just lessen the original value of "u" to add more pages to be scraped.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# import time
# from random import randint
# import xlsxwriter
# import urllib3
# from tinydb import TinyDB, Query

total = 0
u = int(1127)

while u < 2000:
    u = u+1
    url = 'https://www.fanfiction.net/Naruto-Crossovers/1402/0/?&srt=1&lan=1&r=10&p=' + str(u)
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

    raw = soup.find_all('div', class_='z-indent z-padtop')
    for n in range(len(raw)):
        stats = raw[n]
        info = stats.div
        text = info.text
        formatted = text.split(' - ')
        print(formatted[1:(len(formatted))])
```

Comment: I'd start with saving scrap results to list, not to string. Then, it would be nice to have defined columns, by which you'll sort the data into Excel file. Finally, based on that column names, you'll be able to retrieve data from scrap result list (although, that list also will be needed to be formatted). Unfortunately, I can't show some code example, b/c I'm new to python so far, but this is the way, how I'd implement it... Is this feasible solution for you though?

Comment: @kosist All of the results that are returned are already saved to a list.I need to figure out how to find specific words in the strings of the list and find the index of the matching string to save in a specific column in an excel file, since not all of the lists that are returned have the same elements(stats of the story) at the same index or even have the same elements at all.

Comment: ['Naruto & Mythology', 'Rated: K+', 'English', 'Adventure', 'Chapters: 1', 'Words: 2,835', 'Reviews: 2', 'Favs: 6', 'Follows: 1', 'Published: 3/18/2004', 'Kakashi H.', 'Complete']
['Yu-Gi-Oh & Naruto', 'Rated: T', 'English', 'Romance/Humor', 'Chapters: 1', 'Words: 32', 'Reviews: 8', 'Favs: 2', 'Follows: 1', 'Updated: 1/5/2004', 'Published: 12/28/2003'] These are two of the lists that represent two different stories, notice how they both have words as an element and the publish date, but one has an update date and the status of the story(complete) as elements. This affects the indexes i need.

Comment: What should be the overall result? Could you just give an example, based on these 2 lists; for multiple keywords?

Comment: @kosist I would want to search for 'Rated: ' and append the results into a list. I would then have "ratings = ['Rating: K+', 'Rating: T']". I would then search for 'Words: ' and would then have "words = ['Words: 2,835', 'Words: 32']. etc, etc. I would append the results onto the appropriate list when applicable and append a blank space when no value is found, like how the second list doesn't have an update date. It would come out as "updates = ['Updated: 1/5/2004', ' ']", since there was no match for 'Updated: ' in the second list. That way there are just blank excel cells, no mismatched data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then the solution could be like this (check function `find_keyword`)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# import time
# from random import randint
# import xlsxwriter
# import urllib3
# from tinydb import TinyDB, Query

total = 0
u = int(1127)

results = []
while u < 1130: #decreased u due to testing time
    u = u+1
    url = 'https://www.fanfiction.net/Naruto-Crossovers/1402/0/?&srt=1&lan=1&r=10&p=' + str(u)
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

    raw = soup.find_all('div', class_='z-indent z-padtop')
    for n in range(len(raw)):
        stats = raw[n]
        info = stats.div
        text = info.text
        formatted = text.split(' - ')
        if formatted:
            results.append(formatted)
print(results)

# function to search for a keyword
def find_keyword(list, keyword):
    results = []
    for element in list:
        value = ''
        for tag in element:
            if tag.find(keyword) >= 0:
                value = tag
        results.append(value)

    return(results)

words_list = find_keyword(results, 'Words') #example of how to search and build list for keyword
print(words_list)
```

Comment: this code block didn't work for me, but the find function was what I was looking for. I now have all the data sorting into the corresponding lists.

Answer (score 0):

```
This is the code I came up with, it wordks wonderfully. The find function was essential.

# For later use, searches for keywords and adds them to the specified list
    def assign_stats(keyword, stat_list):
        k = 13
        b = 0
        t = 0
        while k >= 1:
            if t == len(formatted):
                t = 0
            check = formatted[t]
            value = check.find(keyword)
            if value != -1:
                # values = formatted[t]
                stat_list.append(check)
                b = 1
            elif k < 2 and b == 0:
                stat_list.append('')

            t = t + 1
            k = k - 1


    # For later use, searches for keywords and adds them to the specified list
    def assign_stats_status(keyword, stat_list):
        k = 13
        b = 0
        t = 0
        while k >= 1:
            if t == len(formatted):
                t = 0
            check = formatted[t]
            value = check.find(keyword)
            if value != -1:
                # values = formatted[t]
                stat_list.append(check)
                b = 1
            elif k < 2 and b == 0:
                stat_list.append('In-Progress')
            t = t + 1
            k = k - 1


    # For later use, searches for specified indexes of story data lists and adds them to specified list
    def assign_stats_concrete(index, stat_list):
        stat_list.append(formatted[index])

    # Searches for keywords/indexes for the specified story stat lists
    assign_stats('Words', words)
    assign_stats_concrete(2, rating)
    assign_stats('English', language)
    assign_stats('Chapters', chapters)
    assign_stats('Reviews', reviews)
    assign_stats('Favs', favorites)
    assign_stats('Follows', follows)
    assign_stats('Updated', updated)
    assign_stats_status('Complete', status)
    assign_stats('Published', published)
    assign_stats_concrete(1, crossover)
```